# How to find maximum number of consecutive one's in a binary number?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the maximum number of consecutive one's in a binary string.

Input: `67`

Expected Output: `2`

My Output: `7`

Explanation: `67` in binary is `1000011`, so the output should be 2. But I'm getting `7` as the output. Can somebody point out the mistake?

Here's the code:

```
public class Test{
    static int getMax(int n)
    {
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        char[] arr = bin.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==0)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                result=Math.max(result,count);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         System.out.println(getMax(67));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: what is the difference between `0` and `'0'`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the if condition to..
if(arr.charAt(i)=='0')

Comment: charAt(i) is really not correct for the type char[]; bin.charAt(i) would work though

Comment: Yeah, I think thats what he meant. I changed it to `bin.charAt(i)` when he told the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the wrong condition (`if (arr[i] == 0)` should be `if (arr[i] == '0')`), you don't need to compute the maximum *every time* in a loop.

Good luck!